# How to find Oracle server crash from OCI Client program

Tags: oracle

I have written a oracle client program using OCI library.

client send a request to server and hung because server crashed and not intimated to client.

How can i find server status from client side(using OCI API).?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think Oracle db module for Asterisk had a nice DCD(dead connection detection) implemented. There are various approaches(server side, client side).

In your case the easiest way would be to use TCP keepalive. Use [`enable=broken`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/tnsnames.htm#CHDCDGCE) directive in tnsnames.ora.

> Purpose
>
> The keepalive feature on the supported TCP transports can be enabled
>   for a net service client by embedding (ENABLE=BROKEN) under the
>   DESCRIPTION parameter in the connect string. Keepalive allows the
>   caller to detect a dead remote server, although typically it will take
>   2 hours or more to notice. Operating system TCP configurables, which
>   vary by platform, define the actual keepalive timing details.

```
net_service_name=
 (DESCRIPTION= 
  (enable=broken)
  (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=sales1-svr)(PORT=1521))
  (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=sales2-svr)(PORT=1521)))
  (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=sales.us.example.com))
```

Just beware you will also need root privileges. With default setting Linux kernel starts sending keepalive packets after 2 hours of inactivity. So you also have to change `tcp_keepalive_time` and `tcp_keepalive_intvl` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. This is global server side settings and Oracle can not yet set keepalive interval for a single TCP connection.

One more comment: I recall there is some function called OCIPing.
This one can be used for testing too. But I'm not sure how to distinguish long running queries from dead server situation.